# how to use @ContextConfiguration to configure values from another project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I configure something like this when the files are in the same project in spring

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml")
```

but I want to configure the few files which are available in another project, how to do this in spring with  `@ContextConfiguration`.

Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml")
```

This asks spring to load **all** `META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml` from the classpath, your project or not (ie. some JAR dependency).

See [`@ContextConfiguration`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html) javadoc

Comment: this will by default take the file from current project, but i want to load the files which are from another project. how to do that?? is it possible, if so could you please explain

Comment: No default here, everything is loaded (note: some shadowing might occurs)

Comment: thanks RC, if they are two different files how to load them? is it possible to load them as comma separated ?

Comment: `@ContextConfiguration(value = { "path/to/file1.xml", "classpath:file2.xml" })` in case you have 2 files

Comment: Good RC, Thanks for the post, it helped me.